# Persistent retries in Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am struggling with making it possible to persist messages for redeliveries in Camel:

```
from("activemq:incoming-queue")
     .errorHandler(
         deadLetterChannel("activemq:queue.dead-letter")
         .maximumRedeliveries(100)
         .redeliveryDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))
     )
.to("http4://example.com")
```

In the event of failure a retry is scheduled and if we shut down Camel it puts messages back in the ActiveMQ queue which is good.

The thing is that if you kill it with "kill -9" messages will be lost forever since Camel holds them in memory during the retries.

**The question is how to guarantee that messages won't be lost on retries even in the case of a sudden outage of the system?**

**UPDATE:**

We implemented guaranteed redelivery using transactions:

```
    @Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
        jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return jmsTransactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Disables ActiveMQ redelivery since it clashes with camel redelivery system
     */
    @Bean
    public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(0);
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        return redeliveryPolicy;
    }
```

Then the route looks as shown below (note the transacted=true parameter, for some reasons .transacted() method behavies differently):

```
from("activemq:incoming-queue?transacted=true")
         .errorHandler(
             deadLetterChannel("activemq:queue.dead-letter")
             .maximumRedeliveries(100)
             .redeliveryDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))
         )
.to("http4://example.com")
```

Are there any disadvantages using this approach?

Answer (score 3):

To make Claus' answer more concrete:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.url}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="${activemq.userName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="100"/>
            <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="10000"/>
            <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="10000"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

retries 100 times with ActiveMQ, waiting 10 seconds for the first retry and then 10 seconds for every subsequent retry.

Then you can omit the error handling in Camel (thus leaving it to ActiveMQ) but I would add transactions:

```
from("activemq:incoming-queue")
     .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_JMS")
     .to("http4://example.com")
```

After 100 retries the messages would end up in the queue "ActiveMQ.DLQ" unless you change that.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasW for your answer. I didn't know that there is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_JMS propagation level. And yeah - involving transactions for us is perfectly fine unless messages are not lost.

Comment: probably you need also to specify that the jmscomponent must be transactions using activemq:incoming-queue?transacted=true

Answer (score 2):

Its better to configure such kind of persistent redeliveries on the ActiveMQ broker side, you can do it as it has such functionality.

- http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html
- http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Comment: Thank you, @Claus Ibsen, for your answer. I updated my answer with a way how we resolved the problem, is there any advantages using ActiveMQ redelivery policy instead?